# Binomial test for absenteeism

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Company | hrs_prev | fsa | fsa/hrs_prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 140 | 5 | 0,035 |
| B | 145 | 2 | 0,01379 |
| C | 140 | 60 | 0,4286 |
| A | 155 | 20 | 0,0129 |
| A | 180 | 25 | 0,1389 |
| B | 120 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 130 | 0 | 0 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc |

Company A, B and C are sub companies from a larger one, say G, `fsa` refers to absenteeism at work and `hrs_prev` is the working hours per month. I want to perform a binomial test to infer if absenteeism in company A, B and C is statistically significant compared to absenteeism in the whole company G.

Thus, I need to compare absenteeism in the whole dataset with absenteeism with subsets only for A, then only for B and then only for C. I want to perform a binomial test but I am not sure on how to do it:

Thinking on heads and tails for testing a coin, I want to consider `fsa/hrs_prev = 0` as, say, heads and `fsa/hrs_prev > 0` as tails, but I am not sure if it makes sense. My comparison would be like: "heads" and "tails" for the whole dataset and "heads" and "tails" for the subset A and a binomial test to test if this "coin" for the subset are biased in some sense when compared to the whole dataset.

In Python, the binomial test is:

```
binom_test(x, n=None, p=0.5, alternative=’two-sided’)
```

If `x` is the number of successes, it would be the count where `fsa/hrs_prev = 0`? and `n` the number of trials would be the `fsa/hrs_prev > 0` + `fsa/hrs_prev = 0`? What about `p` it would be the proportion of `fsa/hrs_prev > 0` and `fsa/hrs_prev = 0`? if so, in the whole dataset or in the subset?

My problem here is how to translate the classical `coin flip` problem to this kind of problem I have in hands. Any help, tips or reference?

Comment: You also have the problem of choosing a meaningful $\alpha$ for your confidence level.

Comment: Why would you want to simplify your data so that fsa/hrs_prev = 5/140 is represented exactly the same way as fsa/hrs_prev = 60 / 140 (ie as tails)? That's a huge loss of information about "absenteeism".